# Run socket.io server in subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cloudflare

I have a website made with `express` and `socket.io`. I tried to use CloudFlare but they said they don't support WebSockets, I have to run socket server in subdomain.

How can I run `socket.io` server in `xxx.mysite.com` and access that socket from `mysite.com` ?

Comment: Well, you're essentially running two separate servers. You can't share runtime objects (socket) between them. You can only have them communicate and exchange information.

Comment: Thank you, can you point me to a tutorial? I guess I have to change architecture of the app..